# Bug fix abandoned Firefox add-on, Wikilook?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

This is just a hopeful appeal really. I know next to nothing about javascript or Firefox add-ons, so I wouldn't know where to even begin, but perhaps someone here can help.

The wonderful Wikipedia based add-on [Wikilook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/wikilook/) was sadly abandoned long ago by its creator. It stopped working altogether around FF#20, but I found [this fix](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wikilook/SX4ik7XffPM) which got it working again and I've been happily using it ever since.

However, one of its main features – popping up when hovering over Wikipedia links – doesn't work if they're http**s**, which of course most of them are nowadays. So what, if anything, can be done to fix this problem?

Comment: This is a good question i think because where else can he ask this, so I dont think it should be closed. I'm not willing to dig into it right now but might later :) Im a bit busy right now :(

Comment: @Noitidart: Thanks. Did someone suggest it should be closed?

Comment: Yea some fool gave you 1 vote for close and a down vote on topci :P

Comment: @Noitidart: Well thanks for defending it. Like you say, where else was I supposed to ask for help with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wikilook code is quite complex. It strips the initial 'http://' (7 characters) from its pre-configured parsers in many places when loading the Wiki webpage. Anything other than changing the code won't help.

*Edits below - new test version*:

- Download this tweaked [wikilook@testpilot.xpi](http://www.onic.cz/wikilook@testpilot.xpi) and place it where it belongs. Step-by-step guide is in your link to Google Groups.
- I have changed the Options window for the add-on and added "Use https?" checkbox for Ctrl parser (Wikipedia by default). When you check this, it will parse both http and https links into Wikipedia.

I tested it **very** briefly and it seems to work.

Comment: Thank you. I've done that, but unfortunately, while changing the Ctrl+Right-click configuration to *"https…"* does the trick, it then stops working on http links. I can see the code you've added attempts to cater for both types, but it looks like the problem goes a bit deeper…

Comment: Awesome of you Olda to look into this.

Comment: @Olda Did you see my earlier comment? I appreciate all your efforts so far and would love to mark this as the answer, but it's not quite the fix I'd hoped for. Is there any chance you could take another look at it, please?

Comment: @Olda: Thank you so much for your work on this. Your latest edit has now got it working exactly as I'd hoped. Initially it seemed to screw up the settings, but clicking on the 'Restore default values' button sorted that out.

Comment: Oh but one small point: I see you're new here so you probably don't know, but if you just edit your answer no-one gets notified and it can very easily get missed. You need to add a tagged comment (eg:  `@<user>`), to notify concerned parties. Thanks again for some terrific work!

Comment: @Olda: In case you see this, I've found a small issue with your modified xpi: because you've appended an 'a' to the version number in the `install.rdf` file – quite sensibly I might add – it causes the original, broken, xpi to get reinstalled by updates. Anyway, rather than turn off automatic updates for the extension I've edited the 'a' out in my copy, just in case the author ever does decide to update it… you never know. :)